# Get Excel file from a Tableau server with desired options

Tags: python, excel, tableau-api

There is a Tableau server which I want to connect to it and download a view as an Excel file with multiple parameters. I have tried to do this by Tableau Server Client (Python). I could find and parse the views but I don't know how I can get available parameters for that view, set my desired options and download the Excel file. It would be great if you could help me. Thanks.